# If you have a break inside an if statement that creates a child process in a for loop, does the loop no longer execute?

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement, fork, break

I am going through a code example in my textbook (dining philosophers problem) and in the main method, right before the return 0; statement, there is the block of code I've included below. This loop is supposed to create the philosophers each as a concurrent forked process. This means that each philosopher executes philosopher(i).

However, since right after the if statement, there follows a break, doesn't that mean only the first philosopher (i = 0) is created?

```
for (i = 0; i < N - 1; ++i)
    if (fork() == 0) 
        break;
philosopher(i) ;
```

Comment: It will only stop if fork() returns zero..  see the answer! It will return the PID of the child normally

Comment: @JeffUK Yes but wouldn't it always return 0 as long as the child process is created successfully?

Comment: @JeffUK: Well, it's not *entirely* unclear -- this is valid C, just not good form since omitting `{}` leads to confusion and often bugs when code is edited, reformatted, etc. (Including some infamous exploits.)

Answer (score 4):

[`fork(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) "splits" the process calling it into two independent processes, the second a child of the first. In the parent process (the original process), it returns the PID of the child. In the child process, `fork()` returns `0`.

So in your example, the loop only breaks in the child process, while continuing in the parent process to spawn the remaining philosophers.

The loop executes `N - 1` times, spawning `N - 1` child philosophers. After completing the loop, the parent process *also* calls `philosopher(i)`, running the `N`th and final philosopher.

Comment: so then how would we get all 5 philosophers?

Comment: @Y.J. - by setting N to 4. The loop will repeat 4 times, each time spawning a subprocess which will call `philosopher(i)`. Then the loop will exit because N will be equal to four, and thus the test `i < N-1` will fail. Then the parent process will call `philosopher(i)`.

Comment: Oh, I thought that fork() would return 0 on the first iteration and break there. Does this mean the first 4 calls to fork() return to a parent process?

Comment: @Y.J.; The parent process never goes away, and because of the `break`, `fork()` is only ever called in the parent process. Multithreaded programming can take some time to grapple with: you have to remember that the values of variables (in this case a sort of implicit variable containing the return value of `fork()`) in different threads are completely independent. `fork()` "happens" in both the parent and the child, which are now independent, but it returns different values.

Comment: @Linuxios Not really but it did help me a bit-I thought fork would also be called in the children processes causing the children to create more children unless I used a return :)

Answer (score 2):

`fork()` returns twice: in the parent with a non-zero value (a positive pid on success or a negative value on failure) and in the child with `pid==0` (if the call succeeded).
`if (fork() == 0)` will `break` the loop in the child, so that the child continues at `philosopher(i);` (where the parent will also continue but only after all the loop iterations are over).

In other words,

```
for (i = 0; i < N - 1; ++i)
    if (fork() == 0) 
        break;
philosopher(i) ;
```

tries to (`fork()` not checked against failure) run `philosopher(i);` in `i=0 to i==N-2 incl.` child processes and then runs it with `i==N-1` in the parent.

Comment: Does the value of fork() stays the same for the parent process? Or does it just keep changing to the PID of the last created child. I'm new to multithreading-my bad!

Comment: @Y.J. The return value wouldn't be very useful if it was the same for each fork.

Comment: This is not multhreading. Threads are parallel execution within a process, while fork() creates an independent process. And when executing fork(), you get its value (either 0 or the pid of the newly created process) and process ids are all different.